# Why is this identity about commutators of Lie derivatives true?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, lie-derivative

I am reading the paper "On splitting methods for Schrödinger-Poisson and cubic nonlinear Schrödinger equations" by Lubich. On page 2147 the author claims

$$[T,V](\psi) = T'(\psi) V(\psi) - V'(\psi) T(\psi) $$

where $T(\psi) = i\Delta \psi$ and $V(\psi) = -i\tilde{V}[\psi]\psi$ with $\tilde{V}([\psi])= \Delta^{-1} |\psi|^2$ where $\psi$ is a complex-valued $H^2$-function on $\mathbb{R}^3$ (so that $\Delta\psi$ is well-defined). It is then claimed that
$$
\begin{split}
 T'(\psi) V(\psi) - V'(\psi) T(\psi) = &\; i\Delta(-i\Delta^{-1}(\psi\bar{\psi}) \psi) + i\Delta^{-1}(-i\Delta \psi \bar{\psi})\psi \\
&\;+ i\Delta^{-1}(\psi  \overline{i\Delta\psi}) + i\Delta^{-1}(\psi\bar{\psi})i\Delta \psi  
\end{split}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
So the derivative in $T'(\psi)$ is probably just some sort of formal derivative with respect to $\psi$ but what would $(i\Delta \psi)'$ be then? The first term in $(1)$ is cleary coming from $T'(\psi)V(\psi)$ but it doesn't make sense to me from the definition of $T'(\psi)$. It would make sense as $T(V(\psi))$, though. So is $T'(\psi)=T(\psi)$ then?

The other terms are confusing as well. Naively, we would have
$$(\tilde{V}[\psi]\psi)' = \tilde{V}[\psi]'\psi + \tilde{V}[\psi]$$
which, again, doesn't fit with what we have in \eqref{1}.

More formal than above, $T$ and $V$ are vector fields and their and the corresponding differential equation is 
$$\partial_t \psi = T(\psi) + V(\psi)$$
In that sense the commutator is the Lie bracket of vector fields.

Maybe someone can give me some clarification?

Comment: What do the square brackets denote i.e $V(\psi) = -i \psi V \color{red}[ \psi \color{red}]$? Also, why is $\psi = \Delta^{-1} \lvert \psi \rvert^{2}$? This is awful notation.

Comment: So $V$ solves the Poisson equation $\Delta V = |\psi|^2$ and the square brackets are just notation from the paper, indicating that $V$ depends on $\psi$. The background of this is the Schrödinger-Poisson system where Schrödinger is coupled to the Poisson equation mentioned above.

Comment: And $\psi = \Delta^{-1}|\psi|^2$ is a typo, I just fixed it.

Comment: If square brackets are just notation indicating that $V$ depends on $\psi$, then what do the _curved_ brackets represent? i.e what does $V \color{red}( \psi \color{red})$ denote that is _different_ to $V \color{red}[ \psi \color{red}]$? I'm just trying to determine what the author has done in the paper so I can help.

Comment: $V(\psi)$ is the action of $V$ on $\psi$, as defined. I probably should have added some distinction like $V$ for the potential and $\hat{V}$ for the vector field.

Comment: So then $V[\psi ] = \Delta^{-1} |\psi|^2$ and $\hat{V}(\psi) = -iV[\psi]\psi$